# Syntax error in subroutine 'Test'

Tags: excel, vba, syntax

I have the following sub function in VBA:

```
Sub test()
    index_match_array(Range("D5").Value,Range("BZ:BZ").DataSeries,"Hardware",1,2)
End Sub
```

This calls the function which starts:

```
Option Explicit
Function index_match_array(loookup As String, table_array As Range, criteria_search As String, criteria_line_add As Integer, return_line_add As Integer) As String()

Dim lookup_array() As String
Dim result_array() As String
...
...
index_match_array = result_array

End Function
```

When I compile I get the error message:

> Compile error:
>   Syntax error

I suspect it's to do with the second parameter, the range one, but I'm not sure?

Comment: `index_match_array Range("D5").Value, Range("BZ:BZ").DataSeries, "Hardware", 1, 2 ` without the () maybe?

Comment: @VincentG Thanks, thats solved the sytnax problem but am now getting a run-time error '424': Object required. The `index_match_array Range("D5")...` is highlighted yellow when click debug

Comment: The function wants to return a string array.  When called it has to go somewhere.  You need a variable which is = to the function call.

Comment: Scott is true, but it is not the reason why you got an error message. The second parameter is expected to be an Object of type Range, and you pass a Variant value (DataSeries).

Comment: Thanks, makes sense. So do I need to change .Dataseries to something else?

Comment: You need to change it to whatever is expected by the function, which I can't invent, you will have to see by yourself (or ask the peoples who made the function)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

' Data Series return type is Variant , Change the table_array to Variant
' Function is in Array, change Function index_match_array to String

```
Option Explicit
Sub test()

    Dim sString(10) As String
    sString(1) = index_match_array(Range("D5").Value, Range("BZ:BZ").DataSeries, "Hardware", 1, 2)

End Sub


Function index_match_array(loookup As String, table_array As Variant, criteria_search As String, criteria_line_add As Integer, return_line_add As Integer) As String

Dim lookup_array(10) As String
Dim result_array(10) As String

result_array(1) = "Test Value"

index_match_array = result_array(1)

End Function
```

Comment: Thanks, just by chaning the data series to variant from range fixed it!